# java object from json (json-api)

Tags: java, json-api

I want to convert a JSON object written with [`json-api` conventions](http://jsonapi.org/) into a Java object. I thought about using the [katharsis library](http://katharsis.io), but I couldn't see if it could be used for this purpose.

Does anyone have any idea how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

in a nutshell: **yes, you can use Katharsis** to convert Json-Objects which follow the Json:API conventions to Java Pojos!

The Katharsis Docs say: "*The Katharsis library adds an additional layer on top of RESTful endpoint to provide easy HATEOAS support for Java by implementing JSON:API standard*."

This Blog Post [Json API in a Java web application](http://www.baeldung.com/json-api-java-spring-web-app) is a step-by-step guide how you could achieve this.

Katharsis offers some [example projects](https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-examples) at their git hub page.

Let me know if you need a working example in spring-boot (1.3.0) with katharsis-spring.

Comment: At the time I asked I don't think it was yet implemented. I figured it out though for what I needed back then. But thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from json - java or from java - json with jackson 
[reference](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: take a look at the link I provided (http://jsonapi.org). Jackson doesn't help me when talking about json-api conventions. There are the "relationships" key and the "included" key and I need something that can solve the binding between these two.

Comment: yes you are right , you have to create the model object by yourself , and this might need too much effort for no reason , if ill find anything related , ill post it , because i have the same problem with some large Json Objects , which have to be mapped in POJO models